# Jquery - dynamically add optgrounp

Tags: jquery, optgroup

I am trying to load categories from one table and then materials from a second using Jquery to use category as optgroup and materials as options. I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: '',
        url: "select_cat.php",
        success: function(cat_data) {

            var sel = $("#material_select");
            sel.empty();

            for (var cat_i=0; cat_i<cat_data.length; cat_i++) {
                // Print header
                sel.append('<optgroup label=' +cat_data[cat_i].cat_displayname+ '>');
                // Get materials from category
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: 'current_material_cat=' + cat_data[cat_i].cat_id,
                    url: "select_mat.php",
                    success: function(data) {

                        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                            sel.append('<option value="' + data[i].value + '">' + data[i].displayname + '</option>');
                        }         
                    }
                }); 

            }     
            $("#material_select").prop("selectedIndex", 0);       
        }
    });
```

However it displays all optgroups first then the materials

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Snce you are using ajax to request the categories they are being loaded asynchronously (not until after the data loads) and so in the mean time the loop adds the other opt groups - so those show up first. Additionally, you are appending the options to the `select` and not to the `optgroup`, which would be the correct way to do it.

So I would make these changes:

Instead of the `for()` loop, use `$.each(cat_data, function() { ... })`

Create a reference to the opt group.

```
var optgroup = $('<optgroup label=' +cat_data[cat_i].cat_displayname+ '>'); 
sel.append(optgroup);
```

Then when the second ajax loads, append the `option` tags to the opt group.

```
optgroup.append('<option value="' + data[i].value + '">' + data[i].displayname + '</option>');
```

This achieves a few things. It creates a scope in which `optgroup` can be maintained through closure and it correctly appends the option to the option group.

Comment: You could also change the inner ajax call to be synchronous by setting the option `async` to `false` - you still need to append to the option group, though.

Comment: Thanks! Both works, but Is there any advantages / disadvantages using async: false instead of the "$.each"?

Comment: In general `async: false` is a very bad idea. Use the promise object natively built into jQuery's `$.ajax()` function instead, and use `$.when()`.

Comment: I'm kind of a newbie with jquery so example code would be appriciated, or should I just go with lemieuxsters answer?